# how to get a better execution plan for empty sets?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan

I have a query I'm trying to optimize, something like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM HugeView
WHERE (Col1 = 'a' AND @val = 1) OR (Col2 = 'a' AND @Val = 0)

(where Col1 and Col2 are on different tables)
```

If I hardcode the `@Val` value (1/0) - SQL Server knows to build an execution plan in which it only accesses the relevant table for either `Col1` or `Col2`.

But when using a variable all the tables in `HugeView` are accessed.

Can you advise on a way of doing it in a way that would help SQL Server not access the unecessary table?

Limitations:

- Can't use `option (recompile)`
- Can't encapsulate this code in an SP
- Can't change `HugeView`

Unfortunately all aforementioned limitations are part of the product's design and/or dev scope - nothing I can do about that - just work within what I have.

I do however know that `@var` is either 1 or 0, and can create and query (and join on) temp or "real" tables as I like.

Also notice I don't select from the tables of `Col1` or `Col2` - I only use them for filtering.

I tried creating and joining on empty tables, or `top(@somevar)` depending on `@var`'s value - but didn't help.

`UNION ALL` won't help as in any case the optimizer doesn't know the value of `@val`. Also can't change the query - if I could then of course all would've been solved.

Comment: Are these local variables? https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reproduce your issue, I created three tables with 1000 rows. The view definition does left outer joins on the primary keys of the table which should allow for join elimination. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BASE_TABLE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO dbo.BASE_TABLE WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values;

CREATE TABLE dbo.COL1_TABLE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, COL1 VARCHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO dbo.COL1_TABLE WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 'A'
FROM master..spt_values;

CREATE TABLE dbo.COL2_TABLE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, COL2 VARCHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO dbo.COL2_TABLE WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 'A'
FROM master..spt_values;

GO

CREATE VIEW HugeView AS
SELECT b.ID AS B_ID, c1.COL1, c2.COL2
FROM dbo.BASE_TABLE b
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.COL1_TABLE c1 ON b.ID = c1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.COL2_TABLE c2 ON b.ID = c2.ID;

GO
```

The following query access all three tables when it shouldn't have to:

```
DECLARE @Val BIGINT = 1;
SELECT 1 FROM dbo.HugeView
WHERE (Col1 = 'A' AND @val = 1) OR (Col2 = 'A' AND @Val = 0);
```

Note the thickness of the arrows in the actual plan:

[image: repro plan]

If I add a `RECOMPILE` hint then I only get two tables in the actual plan as desired:

[image: recompile fix]

Probably the most straightforward fix is to use `UNION ALL`. Here's the estimated plan:

[image: UNION ALL estimated]

At first the plan might look bad because it references all three tables. However, the highlighted startup predicate filter is important:

[image: filter]

What that means is that branch of the query plan may not be executed depending on the value of the parameter. If I get the [actual plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry_pGSzLb) you can see that only one half of the plan was executed:

[image: fix actual]

[dbfiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d9d121aa61e92dd781b80a989107cee0) for everything in this post.

Note that depending on the complexity of the view the startup filter may not appear in the optimal place. However it should save you some amount of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

According to Joe's example, the best way would be to use an `if...else` block. It is better than using `UNION ALL`. However, depending on the complexity of the real query,you could use dynamic SQL using `sp_executesql` (just an idea).

```
DECLARE @Val INT = 1;
if(@val=1)
begin
SELECT 1 FROM dbo.HugeView with (NOLOCK)
WHERE (Col1 = 'A' ) 
end
else if(@val=1)
BEGIN
SELECT 1 FROM dbo.HugeView with (NOLOCK)
WHERE  (Col2 = 'A' )
END
```

...you can check the query plan yourself.

The `NOLOCK` hints are there to prevent reads being blocked by other operations. Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) could also prevent read blocking without dirty reads.

Comment: In the question he said that he can't "Can't encapsulate this code in an SP". That's why I went for a single query approach. What you're proposing here may not be practical.

Comment: what I understood is that , there is one complex view which he can't change,but query on that view using SP.